# Using tidy selection together with the survival package - "Error: promise already under evaluation"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, survival

I am writing an R function that allows the user to specify an individual time variable when creating a `survival::survfit` object. The `survival` package has a "string-free" syntax, which means that the name of the time variable (in my case "dtime") does not need any quotation marks:

```
survival::survfit(formula = survival::Surv(dtime, death) ~ 1, rotterdam)
```

Hence, I figured that I could use tidy evaluation for my purpose. Here is my code:

```
# My function
get_survfit <- function(.data, .time){
  return(survival::survfit(formula = survival::Surv({{ .time }}, status) ~ 1, .data))
}

# Application example
library(survival)
data(cancer)
rotterdam
colnames(rotterdam)[which(names(rotterdam) == "death")] = "status"
get_survfit(.data=rotterdam, .time=dtime)
```

However, I always get the following errors:

> Error in in survival::Surv({ : object 'dtime' not found

and when looking into 'dtime' in the debugger, I get:

> Error during wrapup :
> promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier
> problems?

How can I fix this and still obtain my feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`survfit()` is not a tidy eval function so you're using `{{` out of context. See https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject-out-of-context.html.

Instead you'll need to use `inject()` to enable injection from the outside. Since `survfit()` is not a tidy eval function it won't support quosures, which `{{` creates. So you'll need to use `!!` instead, together with `ensym()`.

```
get_survfit <- function(data, time) {
  time <- ensym(time)

  inject(
    survival::survfit(formula = survival::Surv(!!time, status) ~ 1, data)
  )
}
```

`ensym()` ensures that simple variable names are passed, and defuses them. `!!` injects the variable in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Lionel Henry's answer and inspired by [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70188209/5363942), I would like to add that it is also possible to achieve the same result with `enquo` and `get_expr`:

```r
get_survfit <- function(.data, .time){
  .time = rlang::enquo(.time)
  .time = rlang::get_expr(.time)
  
  rlang::inject(
    return(survival::survfit(formula = survival::Surv(!!.time, status) ~ 1, .data))
  )
}
```