# Handling quoted NULL arguments in rlang::ensym

Tags: r, rlang

I want to use quoted arguments in my function and I would like to allow the user to specify that they don't want to use the argument by setting it to `NULL`. However, `rlang::ensym` throws an error when it receives a `NULL` argument. Here is my code:

```
f <- function(var){
  rlang::ensym(var)
  return(var + 2)
}

# This works
variable = 2
f(variable)
# This throws an error
f(NULL)
```

The error message is:

```
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

I already tried adding an if-clause with `is.null(var)` before the expression with `rlang::ensym`, but of course, this doesn't work as the variable is not yet quoted at this time.

How can I check that the supplied quoted variable is `NULL` in order to handle it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to allow for NULL, it's more robust to use quosures first. Then you can inspect the quosure to see what's inside. For example

```
f <- function(var){
  var <- rlang::enquo(var)
  if (rlang::quo_is_null(var)) {
    var <- NULL
  } else if (rlang::quo_is_symbol(var)) {
    var <- rlang::get_expr(var)
  } else {
    stop(paste("Expected symbol but found", class(rlang::get_expr(var))))
  }
  return(var)
}
```

And that returns

```
f(variable)
# variable
f(NULL)
# NULL
f(x+1)
# Error in f(x + 1) : Expected symbol but found call
```

Or you can use whatever logic is appropriate for your actual requirements.